# How do I change watts on my light?

Tags: lighting

I have a light (point) but I need to change the watts because it is very dark. Plz help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the light in the 3D View then on the bottom-right <kbd>Properties</kbd> panel, click the green light bulb icon. Then you'll see the <kbd>Power</kbd> entry and can change the wattage there.

[image]